# How to end a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to do a simple example of recursion functions (Both Direct and Indirect) and I can't seem to get it to end can you please help me and explain why? (Also I'm trying to do both Direct and Indirect in this program) Thank you for your help.

```
int Print();
int main()
{
    Print();
    return 1;
}
int Print()
{
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        printf("%d",i);
        i++;
    }while(i<10);
    if(i==9)
        return 1;
    Print();
}
```

Edit: The recursion direct and indirect, the direct is supposed to be called from inside the same function and the indirect is supossed to be called from outside the function, also I apologize for not formatting and skipping the while

Comment: it should be `do....while`...that `do` you have only happens once and i will never be 9...one solution make `int i=0` to `static int i=0`

Comment: Please, properly format your code. It is just unreadable.

Comment: @MrAlan Please elaborate what the "direct" and "indirect" functions must do.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: A recursive functions always need access to external variables. Either passed as a parameter or a global variable (which I would not suggest). Your Print function uses only a local variable

Answer (score 3):

Let `i` be a parameter of the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Print(int);
int main()
{
    Print(9);
    return 1;
}
int Print(int i)
{
    if (i <= 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    printf("%d",i);
    return Print(i-1);
}
```

The `do...while` part seems weird, are you sure you need that?

Comment: No, I didn't need it, but I was just testing it, also it works, thank you very much.

Comment: @MrAlan If the answer is satisfactory, you can accept/upvote it. Thanks

Comment: oh sorry first time here didn't know that D: Thanks again!

Comment: @coredump In the original post the function does not have a parameter.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow And that's very bad, it should have a parameter.

Comment: @coredump It is not bad. It is interesting how to implement the function without a parameter that is how to implement the original function in the question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, and that's more like a hack in that case. Don't have anything against hacks, but I'd rather have boring, normal functions which takes parameters when reviewing code.

Answer (score 1):

*i* will never be 9 in your case. Hence calling of Print() again and again.

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

As for the recursive function (that shall be declared when it is defined like `int Print( void )`) then there are several problems.

The first one is that the function returns nothing though it has the return type `int`.

```
int Print()
{
    // ...
    Print();
}
```

Secondly due to the do-while loop

```
do
{
    printf("%d",i);
    i++;
}while(i<10);
```

the condition in this statement

```
if(i==9)
    return 1;
```

is never true because after the loop the variable `i` is equal to `10`. So the function has an indefinite recursion.

And instead of a loop you should use a call to the function itself.

The functions can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void direct_print( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    static int i = N;

    if ( --i ) 
    {
        direct_print();
    }
    printf( "%d ", i );
    ++i;
}

void reverse_print( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    static int i = N;

    printf( "%d ", --i );

    if ( i ) 
    {
        reverse_print();
    }
    ++i;
}


int main(void) 
{
    direct_print();
    putchar( '\n' );
    reverse_print();
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Or a more straightfoward approach to define the functions `direct_print` and `reverse_print` is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

void direct_print( void )
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;
    static unsigned int i;

    if ( i < N )
    {
        printf( "%u ", i++ );
        direct_print();
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}

void reverse_print( void )
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;
    static unsigned int i;

    if ( i < N )
    {
        printf( "%u ", N - ++i );
        reverse_print();
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    direct_print();
    putchar( '\n' );
    reverse_print();
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that the functions would be more flexible if instead of the magic number `10` within the bodies of the functions they used a parameter.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void direct_print( unsigned int n )
{
    static unsigned int i;

    if ( i == 0 ) i = n;

    if ( n )
    {
        printf( "%u ", i - n );
        direct_print( n - 1 );
    }

    if ( i == n ) i = 0;
}

void reverse_print( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n-- )
    {
        printf( "%u ", n );
        reverse_print( n );
    }
}


int main(void) 
{
    direct_print( 10 );
    putchar( '\n' );
    reverse_print( 10 );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same as shown for the previous program

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Vlad from Moscow did already great writeup on the OP problems.

I would like to add a solution with the stop_condition.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Print(int i, int stop_condition);

int main(void)
{
  Print(0, 10);
  putchar( '\n' );

  return 0;
}

void Print(int i, int stop_condition)
{
    printf("%d ",i++);

    if(i<stop_condition)
        return Print(i, stop_condition);
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function return condition `if(i==9)` will never meet, as it is always `i=10`. So your `Print()` function being keep calling recursively forever. First of all you need a situation exactly at what condition/situation you need to use a recursive function? In your example you are printing values from 1 to 9 with the help of a `while loop`. Now how can you achieve the same by using a recursive function?

```
 void Print(int i)
 {
       if( i == 0 )//when i become 0 you are not printing but returning 
          return;
       else
          Print(--i);//decrement the value by one each time you are calling it recursively
       printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

And you are calling it like:-

```
Print(10); // now it will print from 1 till 10;
```

But how it works? When you first time call this function with parameter 10, in the condition `if(i == 0)` it will fail as value of `i` in the first call is 10. In that condition O/S will store all the intermediate data/output (in this case it will store i = 10;) and function's IP(instruction pointer, last execution status that is `Print(--i);` which was the last executed statement in each  recursive functions) in a stack. And it will call with `Print(9);` in the first recursive call(Print(--i)). This whole process will continue till `Print(0)`. But when it call with `Print(0)` function will return without printing the value as it will return after condition `if( i == 0 )` because here `i` became `0`. From this point it will return to the previous call. How it returns to previous call? Once a recursive function return it `pop`s the stack and get the `IP` first and it's intermediate outputs i.e. value of `i`. In this case when it returns for the first time, `i`'s current values is `1`, so in the `printf` it will print 1. As that is the last line of the function and as per IP that is the remaining instruction to be execute. So it will return normally. Now it will get the IP from the stack where function's variable `i`'s intermediate value was 2 so it will print `2` and return and this will continue till it reached in first call where it's value was `10` and after it print `10` it will return to main.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

This is an finite loop using recursion, factorial of 5

```
              i = 5;
              fact=1;
               while(i)
              {
                 fact = fact*i;
                  i- -;
              }
```